# Checking Login Status , Google oAuth, without rendering button

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-signin

#### My Problem

I have a login page that gives the user the option to "Login With Google".

When the user successfully logs in, I am storing their username and Google ID in the Session.

My problem is, on pages OTHER than the login page, I need to check to see if they are logged in. I am having problems getting this to work. If they are not logged in, I need to know that - putting in a simple global page variable for now would be suffice.

**This code handles the login: ( the renderButton function is called immediately on page load )**

```
var googleID;  // global variable to hold ID
var token;     // will hold token ( once I get this working )
// Render Google Sign-in button
function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
    });
}

// Sign-in success callback
function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });

        request.execute(function (resp) {
            // GET GOOGLE ID
            googleId = resp.id;
        });
    });
}

// Sign-in failure callback
function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error);
}

// Sign out the user
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
       loggedIn = false;
    });

    // Change Link
    document.querySelector("#loginNav").innerHTML = "Login";

    auth2.disconnect();
}
```

So this **all works great** on the login page.

But on my other pages, for instance my index page, how to I check to see if they are logged in?

I am trying this code, but getting NOTHING - no error, no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test Login</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="loginStatus">Status</div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
    <script>

        var auth2; // Global
        var loggedIn; 


        function init() {
            var appStart = function () {
                gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);
            };

        }


            /**
             * Initializes Signin v2 and sets up listeners.
             */
            var initSigninV2 = function () {
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: 'MY-CLIENT--ID-HERE',
                    scope: 'profile'
                });

                if (auth2.isSignedIn.get() == true) {
                    alert("Loggin in!");
                    loggedIn = "LOGGED IN";
                } else {
                    alert("Not Logged IN!!!");
                    loggedIn = "NOT LOGGED IN";
                }

               document.getElementById("loginStatus").innerHTML = loggedIn;

            }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me get this working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.

Once logged in the first time, I simply saved the user credentials in a local storage variable.

Then on subsequent pages, I check that variable.

It's not fool-proof, but for my basic needs it works.